# C++/C# Python Hook

Tags: c#, c++, python, hook, code-injection

I've searched good and Stack Overflow but couldn't find an answer to what I was looking for. Is there anyway to hook the call of Python functions from within C++/C#? Capture the function call plus it parameters?

Edit with an example:

def a(pOne):
 //do stuff

def b():
 a("a")

So on the call to 'a' I want C++ to hook that function (assuming the function name is known) and execute a C++ function/event on the call to 'a' with the parameters passed to the C++ function/event being the value of what was passed in for 'pOne'.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Are you looking to build a C++ program that has an embedded (and hooked) interpreter? Hook every instance of Python.exe that runs on the system? Or…?

Comment: I added an example in my original post. But no, hook a known/specific instance.

Comment: Do you really need to hook the function `a` defined in the Python code, or do you just want a way to write a function in C++ and expose it to Python, so it can be called as, say, `foocpp.a("a")`? The latter is really easy; the former is much more complicated.

Comment: No I need to hook. So I have an external C++ Application that will hook the call to 'a'. The call to 'a' is happening from within the Python application itself and just want to passively listen for it I guess you could say.

Comment: Can you explain what you actually want to accomplish here? This smells like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)—and, worse, one where the Y is something very hard that requires a lot of background knowledge you probably don't have and will need to learn before you can even get started.

Comment: I see you have this comment http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14968190/c-c-python-hook#comment21019768_14969099

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There a couple of different options for C++ depending on what you want to do.

The best way to do what you want to do is to 'extend' Python.

My Favorite way to do this is [Boost.Python](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/python/)

You can also use the raw [C-API](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/) though I wouldn't recommend this.

For some examples of embedding and extending with Boost.Python you can look at [this](https://github.com/anhstudios/swganh/tree/develop/src/swganh/scripting) project I have been working on.

Comment: I never thought about looking at boost. Thanks I'll give that a look.

Comment: Could you provide an example?

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the OP's actual question. Building an extension module doesn't hook existing Python code from outside…

Comment: @abarnert you build the extension module to allow you to interact with the C++ code. Then you embed the python within your application to be able to pass values back and forth. Check out my project above, we have a scripting system that allows us to do what the OP suggests he wants and it has nothing to do with intercepting calls.

Comment: Yes, that's a perfectly reasonable thing to do, but it's not the same as hooking a Python interpreter from the outside so whenever the interpreter tries to execute the `a()` function some other code gets run…

Comment: @abarnert if you inherit the Python class from a c++ class then you can absolutely have a() function call the C++ code. I guess, I see where you are coming from, and it probably doesn't make sense to discuss this further as the OP is going to need to do a lot of reading to understand what we're talking about. :)

Comment: @KyleC: Look at his code: He's defining a function `a` in Python, and he wants to make different C++ code get called instead, without changing the Python. Class inheritance won't help at all there. Ultimately, my point is this: If the OP knew what he wanted to do, your answer would probably be ideal. But as it is, I think you may have misled him, and he'll be back later to ask effectively the same question, and someone will have to start over again explaining it to him. Ideally, I'd rather get him to do some reading and figure out what he actually wants sooner…

Comment: @KyleC this approach wouldn't work with *non-embedded*, standard CPython installation, plain interpreter, would it?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to write some C++ code and make it callable from Python, you do that by [Extending and Embedding the Python Interpreter](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/index.html#extending-index). (Actually, just Extending; ignore the other half.)

Basically, if you write a new module `foo`, anyone can `import foo` and call `foo.a("a")`, and it doesn't matter if module `foo` is implemented as a Python file `foo.py`, or compiled from `foo.cpp` into a dynamic library `foo.so`.

For that, as Kyle C suggests, there are a number of higher-level ways to do this so you don't need to deal with the C API directly. (In addition to his suggestion of Boost.Python, I'd also suggest looking at [`Cython`](http://www.cython.org), which lets you write the code in an almost-Python language that can talk directly to your C++, while also exposing things directly to Python.)

However, that isn't what you asked for. What you want to be able to do is take some function that's defined in Python code, and hook it to do something different. For that, you really do need to read the Extending and Embedding documentation linked above. You're going to have to write an embedded interpreter, reproduce some of the behavior (exactly how much depends on where exactly you want to hook it), and make sure that wherever `PyObject_Call` or a similar function would have been called, it first checks whether that object is the `a` function and, if so, calls your hook code.

This is going to be pretty difficult. If you haven't written an embedded Python interpreter yet, go do that before you even think about how to hook it.

It's worth noting that it's probably much, much easier to do the hooking from within Python than from outside the interpreter. (If you've never heard of "monkeypatching", go google that.) And you can always make your Python hook call code from a module that you built in C++, or even call directly into a compiled .so file via `ctypes`.

---

Finally, if you want to hook some running interpreter instance at runtime, that's even more difficult. You obviously need to be able to do some kind of debug/trace/etc. attach and code insertion, and the details of that are entirely dependent on your platform. Then, you'll want to do the same thing you would have done in the previous hard version, except that you'll have to do it by intercepting calls to, e.g., `PyObject_Call` (from `libpython.so`/`Python.dll`/`Python.framework`/whatever) to go through your hooks first. If you don't already know how to hook SO calls on your platform, you need to learn that before you can even think about hooking Python code from outside.

Comment: I've given up this idea, I was just messing around but this sounds like it more trouble then its worth. Bassicaly I have a small Python app I wrote, the idea was to inject a C++ DLL into the running python process and have that injected DLL hook a Python function and when the function is called do something on the C++ side. I was think is like having the C++ passively watch for Python function calls and then doing something when a function was called.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have reasons not to alter the in-python code? If not, why not write an extension module or a python [ctypes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) call [to your dll](http://python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html), and wrap `a` with a decorator that calls your hook?

```
import my_cpp_module
def hook_a_to_call_my_cpp_module(orig_a):
    def replacement_a(pOne):
        try:
            my_cpp_module.my_cpp_function(pOne)
        finally:
            return orig_a(pOne)
    # 
    return replacement_a

@hook_a_to_call_my_cpp_module
def a(pOne):
    pass
```

you can even do this without touching the source file which has `a`, like this:

```
# in this other file you import the module that contains function a
import the_py_that_has_a

# next line just to avoid copy-pasting the above code from my answer here again
from the_decorator_from_the_previous_example import hook_a_to_call_my_cpp_module

the_py_that_has_a.a = hook_a_to_call_my_cpp_module(the_py_that_has_a.a)
```

If you have some reasons *not* to alter your py code *at all*, could you state them in a comment?